# Trigger event with same ID elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, attr

I have a menu list that refer to different projects.

Each list item shares its "ID" with a project showcased in a gallery.

```
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li id="id1">project 1</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="proc id="id1">project 1</div>
</div>
```

I'd like a jQuery function that :

When a list item from the menu is clicked, gets the project with the same id to do something.

I really don't know where to start from and I'm stuck at that :

```
<script>
$( "li#id1").click(function() {
  $( ".project#id1" ).show();
});
</script>
```

Many thanks

Comment: same ID element??? IDs should be unique.

Comment: ^ that, and you have a missing quote in `class="proc id="id1"`

Comment: Make it something like `data=id="id1"` and then use `$('.project[data-id="id1"]')`

Comment: thanks guys, do you have an idea of what my script should look like ?

Comment: Why are you calling non-existant class `.project`? Your html markup and jQuery is a mess. Read around a bit: https://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said the IDs must be unique and you have missing quote.
You can use **data attributes** to handle your logic or combination of ids and data attributes.

Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li data-project-id="first-project-id">project 1</li>
  ...
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="proc" data-project-id="first-project-id">project 1</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.menu li').click(function(){
   var targetId = $(this).attr('data-project-id');
   $('.proc[data-project-id="' + targetId + '"]').show();
});
```

The click event is attached to every li item in the element with class .menu.
On click event we extract the data-project-id attribute from the clicked element, find the project elemenet from gallery and show it.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f6thn/)

Comment: Working good, thanks so much. Need to dig this attr thing though.

Comment: in this case you could also use $(this).data("project-id"); instead of the attr.  Either works fine.  Just pointing it out for completeness.

Comment: The data attributes let you define your own attributes that are also valid HTML5 attributes. You can use them whenever you find them useful. Here is a good read about data attributes: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

you can use normal id also (as selector)

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li id="first-project-id">project 1</li>
...
</ul>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
<div class="proc" id="first-project-id">project 1</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.menu li').click(function(){
var targetId = $(this).attr('id');
$('.proc[id="' + targetId + '"]').toggle();
});
```